# Trying to set the OpenLayers MouseOver position to be outside the Map

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinates, mouse-position

This is my code and I am trying to obtain the MouseOver to be displayed outside the Map container.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="openlayers/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
        <style>
            #map-id {
                width: 1024px;
                height: 512px;
            }
             #location {
                float: right;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="openlayers/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Map</h1>
        <div id="map-id"></div>
        <script>
            var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map-id");
            var bio = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
              "bio11",
              "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/iPlant/wms",
              {layers: 'iPlant:bio11'}
            );
            var imagery = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Global Imagery",
                "http://maps.opengeo.org/geowebcache/service/wms",
                {layers: "bluemarble"}
            );
            map.addLayers([imagery, bio]); //map.addLayers([untiled, tiled]);
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({element: $('location')}));
            map.zoomToMaxExtent();
        </script>
        <script>
            map.events.register("click", map , function(e){
            var latlon = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy) ;
            var lat = Math.round(latlon.lat);
            var lon = Math.round(latlon.lon);
            document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = "The Latitude is " + lat + " and the Longitude is " + lon;
            //window.location = "http://niles.iplantcollaborative.org/demo/geo/geo/iplantgeo_cgi.py?get=env&from=latlon&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon;
            });

        </script>
        <div id="location">Position</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using the , the mouse over co-ordinates are only appearing at the bottom right of the map (within the map container).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your code would be worked, when your main code was in body tag of init...

if not, try to change:

```
var latlon = this.events.getMousePosition(e);
......
......
OpenLayers.Util.getElement("location").innerHTML = ....
```

and put them all `init()` function which will locate in `body`...
you can check source code of [mouse position control](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/mouse-position.html) example.

.

**UPDATE:**

ok. sorry for the late answer, i have newly noticed that sth wrong with the above code.

try to change sth like this, it will give you the same result as `OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition()` give:

```
map.events.register("mousemove", map, function(e) { 
    var position = this.events.getMousePosition(e);
    var latlon = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy) ;
    var lat = Math.round(latlon.lat);
    var lon = Math.round(latlon.lon);               
    OpenLayers.Util.getElement("coords").innerHTML = "The Latitude is " + lat +
        " and the Longitude is " + lon;
});
```

i hope it helps you....

Comment: Ok there is a issue, the x, y co-ordinates not exactly as it should be. If u compare in the link that you gave me, the co-ordinates in the Map control and in the div are not same. The div is giving back some kind or reference values. There is no negative co-ordinates

Comment: i have updated my answer..

Comment: Thanks man that works. just one question
Why did u need this line,
`var position = this.events.getMousePosition(e);`

Comment: Oh sorry. i have forgetten to delete the line, you mentioned...